# XML Serialize Collections doesn't appear in XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an class that inherits the interface ICollection as seen on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx) website, however, it is not appearing on my XML. What could possibly be wrong? Why isn't my XMLSerializer including the `AssertionAttribute` Collection? As for my examples, I apologize in advance for the ton of coding attached.

XML produced for this Element:

```
    <saml:AttributeStatement xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

XML Expected to be produced from my example:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="Language">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">en-US</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="fromApp">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">SP2</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="Action">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">VSREPORT</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
```

Code:

**AttributeStatement.cs**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
public class AttributeStatement
{
    private static AssertionAttributes attributes = new AssertionAttributes();

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Attribute")]
    public static AssertionAttributes attribute;

    public AttributeStatement()
    {
        xmlns.Add("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        SetAttributes();
    }

    private static void SetAttributes()
    {
        var languageAttribute = new AssertionAttribute("en-US");
        languageAttribute.Name = "Name";
        attributes.Add(languageAttribute);

        var fromAppAttribute = new AssertionAttribute("SP2");
        fromAppAttribute.Name = "fromApp";
        attributes.Add(fromAppAttribute);

        var actionAttribute = new AssertionAttribute("VSREPORT");
        actionAttribute.Name = "Action";
        attributes.Add(actionAttribute);

        attribute = attributes;
    }
}
```

**AssertionAttributes.cs** - The class should hold a collection of Type AssertionAttribute

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")]
public class AssertionAttributes : ICollection
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    public AssertionAttributes()
    {
        xmlns.Add("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
    }

    private ArrayList empArray = new ArrayList();

    public AssertionAttribute this[int index]
    {
        get { return (AssertionAttribute)empArray[index]; }
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        empArray.CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    int ICollection.Count
    {
        get { return empArray.Count; }
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return empArray.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(AssertionAttribute assertionAttribute)
    {
        empArray.Add(assertionAttribute);
    }
}
```

**AssertionAttribute.cs** - Should appear as multiple tags in xml (as produced)

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")]
public class AssertionAttribute
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "NameFormat")]
    public string NameFormat = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic";

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AttributeValue")]
    public AttributeValue attributeValue;

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    public AssertionAttribute(string attributeValueText)
    {
        xmlns.Add("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        AttributeValueText = attributeValueText; 
        attributeValue = new AttributeValue(attributeValueText);
    }

    private string name;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private static string attributeValueText;

    public static string AttributeValueText
    {
        get { return attributeValueText; }
        set { attributeValueText = value; }
    }

}
```

**AttributeValue.cs** - An XML value simply to store a text value for this element

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")]
public class AttributeValue
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    public AttributeValue(string attributeValueText)
    {
        xmlns.Add("saml", "urn.oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        Text = attributeValueText;
    }

    private string text;

    [XmlText]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default during XML serialization, only the public properties and fields of an object are serialized. Your `AssertionAttribute` is a public field, so it should be serialized, right? Actually, no: note the word `object` :). Since `AssertionAttribute` is `static`, it's a field of the class, but not of objects of the class. If you can arrange things such as to remove the `static` modifier, that should do it.